# spacemacs counsel-locate cannot find files in ~/Document

Tags: emacs24, spacemacs

when using `counsel-locate` SPC f L on mac, cannot find any file in `~/Documents` or `~/Download`.

I googled this, one answer on stackoverflow says I should install `GNU locate`, but how?